# ColdFusion 9 Script upload function not working

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfml

I'm having trouble using ColdFusion 9.0.0 fileUpload() cfscript function. I'm getting this error message:

"Variable FILEUPLOAD is undefined."

Here is my code:

```
result = fileUpload(application.uploadPath, "attachment", "application/*, image/*", "makeUnique");
```

As an alternate solution, I was able to get it to work with the suggestion here [Script function for file upload in ColdFusion 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231289/script-function-for-file-upload-in-coldfusion-9) .

The fileUpload() function works on my local desktop running ColdFusion 9.0.1. I curious if anyone has gotten it to work on ColdFusion 9.0.0.

thanx

Comment: How are you including the function definition into your application? If it's in a CFC, you'll have to reference it as `cfcInstance.fileUpload()`. If you embed the `<cffunction>` definition in the same template as you are calling it, then it should work by calling simply `fileUpload()`.

Comment: is there any reason why it's not upgraded to cf901?

Comment: It in a CFC and I'm using CFWheels framework. Here's what my create() looks like.
    public any function create(){

  processlinks = model("ProcessLinks").new(params.processlinks);
    
 if (processlinks.save()){
    if(params.attachment != ''){
      result = fileUpload(application.uploadPath, "attachment", "application/*, image/*", "makeUnique");
      if(result.fileWasSaved) {        
        attachments = model(name="Attachments").new(attachment=result.serverFile, ProcessLinksID=processlinks.id);
        attachments.save();
      }
    }    
  }
}

Comment: I've been waiting for the admin to update for some time now. Thought I see if anyone had any luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the docs for `fileUpload()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSd160b5fdf5100e8f36f73035129d9e70a92-8000.html) (always a good place to start with these sorts of questions):

> **History**
>
> ColdFusion 9.0.1: Added this function.

Which kinda explains why it doesn't work in CF9.0. To "make it work" you're gonna need to roll your own, or perhaps [`uploadFile()`](http://www.cflib.org/udf/uploadFile) on cflib might be an option.

Comment: That's what I figure. Thanks Adam, appreciate the response.

Answer (score 0):

One other thing to maybe note with FileUpload(), is that, unlike the cffile tag-based equivalent, it doesn't give you the option to specify a "mode" (e.g. 777). So when being run on a linux servers where permissions are restricted then you can encounter some strange behaviour!

I wonder if anyone else has encountered this? or has heard of a workaround?

FileUpload() Doc:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSd160b5fdf5100e8f36f73035129d9e70a92-8000.html